# Xamarin Essentials Permissions.RequestAsync does not return

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, permissions, xamarin.essentials

When calling `Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>()` I do not get any result and the App is getting stuck. No matter, if the user accepts or denies the request.

I've set up `MainActivity` as described in the documentation:

```
public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Now I'm trying to get the permissions the following way. But the `RequestAsync` call is just getting stuck and I never recieve an answer. Once the permission is granted and the app is being restarted, everything works as expected.

```
public async Task CheckPermissions()
{
    var status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

    if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
    }
    

    if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
    {
        HasLocationPermissions = true;
    }
    else if (status != PermissionStatus.Unknown)
    {
        HasLocationPermissions = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Farther up your call stack, do you have a call to `.Wait()`, `.Result`, or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: @StephenCleary Thank you very much for your hint! I had a `.Wait()` when calling the `CheckPermissions()` method. Removing that solved my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A synchronous blocking call further up your call stack can cause this; e.g., `.Wait()`, `.Result`, or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. This is the [classic deadlock situation](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) described on my blog.

Since you are writing a Xamarin application, you may find [this technique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) helpful - it's a way to start an asynchronous operation (synchronously), show a "loading..." state, and then update when the asynchronous operation completes.